# JavaScript --- Looping through elements in webpage #2 from webpage #1

Tags: javascript

Totally new to JavaScript. As in, today.

From an `.html` file on my MacBook desktop, I want to open ***TWO*** webpages. The first is the file itself, say from the command line, as follows:

```
open ~/Desktop/first.html
```

The second webpage is one that I call from the `first.html` file:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>JavaScript stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            w = window.open('https://fireship.io/courses/javascript/beginner-js-where-to-run/');
            const elements = w.document.querySelectorAll('*');
            const count = elements.length;
            alert(count)
            elements.forEach((elem) => {
                console.log(elem)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***WHAT I WANT TO BE HAPPENING*** is that `w.document.querySelectorAll('*')` is getting all elements in the second webpage, meaning https://fireship.io/courses/javascript/beginner-js-where-to-run/. ***WHAT'S ACTUALLY HAPPENING***, though, is that the elements from `first.html` are returning. This is confirmed by inspecting the console output of `first.html`.

So, my general question is --- How do I loop through the elements of one webpage from scripting that resides in another?

Any help or direction is much appreciated!

Justin

Comment: Can't touch second window from first, unless the second webpage gives you permission (allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header accordingly).

Comment: Thanks @Amadan --- well, that's a bummer. Is there another way I should be doing this? How do you loop through the elements of a webpage without injecting javascript into that webpage? I mean, it's not MY webpage. So, how do people loop through elements in pages they don't own?

Comment: They don't, not in a browser. That's the whole point of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (and indirectly CORS as the process to circumvent it when needed). You might as well ask "how do people get jewellery from safes they don't own". Non-browser code is not subject to this security mechanism, so the only way to do what you want is to not use browser-based JavaScript. Node.js, Python, Ruby, etc will all be able do it.

Comment: LOL :) Great answer, @Amadan. Thanks for the security perspective. Off to learn how to do this in Node.js! (Perhaps Python.) I appreciate it!